# PHP best way to convert an array into a very particular string

Tags: php, arrays, string

What i'm trying to do is to convert an array of strings

```
$array = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'];
```

into something like:

```
$string = 's.sting1, s.string2, s.string3';
```

I'm not very good with string manipulation and looking for a neat way to write a function that does this conversion.

(ps: "s." and "," are just hardcoded characters)

Comment: You could consider `array_reduce`?

Comment: took a look the the function `implode()`;

Comment: Are there any rules behind this conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple implode function:

```
<?php
$array = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'];

$string = 's.' . implode(',s.', $array);

echo $string;
```

[PHP online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=64e21500142761f1ff8a2eae1bc6d156&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)